# How to do a vlookup in python and use SQL's LIKE operator as input

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, vlookup, string-comparison

I have two datasets, qlik_clean and synapse_clean. Qlik_clean contains 1 column of type string (col= field) and synapse_clean contains of 2 columns (cols= field, model), both of which are of type string.

My goal is to compare and find out which rows of col field in qlik_clean are also in col field in synapse_clean and return either true OR the value of col model for that specific row.

I have tried using pandas and lambda functions, but with no success. I have converting the df to a dict and go from there, but with no success either.

Could someone help out and point me in the right direction? I have my code below, I haven't added any comparison logic yet, would anyone know the way to go here?

Kind regards,

Rutger

`import pandas as pd`
`import openpyxl`
`import re`

````
#open synapse fields file
synapsefilepath = ''
synapse = pd.read_excel(synapsefilepath, engine='openpyxl')
#create df from synapse file
synapse_df = pd.DataFrame(synapse)```

#transform fields into list
synapse_dict = synapse_df.to_dict('list')

#all keys and values to lower
synapse_clean = {k.lower(): str(v).lower() for k, v in synapse_dict.items()}


##### QLIK FILE #######
#open qlik file
qlikfilepath= ''
qlik = pd.read_excel(qlikfilepath, engine='openpyxl', sheet_name='qliksynapsecomp')
#create df from excel file and keep only qlikfieldname and insynapse
qlik_df = pd.DataFrame(qlik)
qlik_df_trunc = qlik_df[['field']]

#transform fields into list
qlik_dict = qlik_df_trunc.to_dict('list')

#lowercase all keys and values
qlik_clean = {ke.lower().strip(): str(va).lower().strip() for ke, va in qlik_dict.items()}
````

Answer (score 0):

I can't get a good idea of your dataframes structures from the posted code, but I think this should answer your question.

To filter df1 by values in df1.col1 that are in df2.col1:

```
df1[df1.col1.isin(df2.col1)]
```

Ex;

```
>>> df1
   A  B  C  D
0  6  5  9  6
1  4  1  6  3
2  3  4  6  9
3  0  6  0  5
4  1  6  3  3
>>> df2
   A  B  C  D
0  6  4  5  4
1  4  3  6  9
2  2  2  8  5
3  6  6  7  3
4  7  0  1  7
>>> df1[df1.A.isin(df2.A)]
   A  B  C  D
0  6  5  9  6
1  4  1  6  3
```

You had mentioned something about a SQL LIKE statement, but also mentioned that you are not working with strings. If I misunderstood and you need to do partial string matching, let me know.

Comment: the solution does not hand partial pattern matching using text.  try using regular expressions for the pattern matching

Comment: Hi, thanks for taking the time to find an answer! My apologies for not providing the full information. Qlik_df contains 1 column that is of type string and synapse_df contains 2 columns that are also of type string.

Comment: I made some changes to the question, hope its more specific now?

Comment: Add a column E that contains text then demonstrate partial pattern matching from one dataframe into another for that column

Comment: @rutgerv Can you post some examples of the text you are trying to match? Wil the string from df1 be equal to a string in df2, or will it be part of the string in df2? ie; match 'run' with 'run' OR match 'run' with 'run fast' ?

Comment: @Boskosnitch It can be both. There can be exact matches, as well as partial matches..